# Raspberry pi : How can combine v2 noir camera with IR lamp

Tags: raspberry-pi, lamp

[image]

Raspberry pi : How can combine V2 NOIR camera with IR lamp.

LED link :
[https://www.amazon.com/Infrared-High-power-Illuminator-Adjustable-Raspberry/dp/B01M3U8DIT/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=ir+led&qid=1552478686&s=electronics&sr=1-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M3U8DIT)

V2 NOIR camera

I screwed noir camera with led but it didn't work.
Does led need resistance or more power?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't concern programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work, because you are not powering it. Holes on camera module where you screwed it are not powered. You must wire it from RPi's 5V pin.